# Custom Heroku Domain Not Resolving Properly

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to use a custom domain for a Heroku app. My domain is registered on Dynadot.com. Below is a screenshot of my DNS configuration. Now my domain goes to a "No Such App" in Heroku, and adding www. just doesn't resolve anywhere.

[image: dynadot]

I'm trying to avoid using an addon for custom DNS management. This shouldn't be that complicated for a statically generated, free heroku app.

And yes, I did read all the documentation, and almost all Heroku custom domain questions on Stackoverflow. I followed the instructions and it still won't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku recommends your apex domain be forwarded to a `www` subdomain (or similar), and then that subdomain be a `CNAME` to your `app-name.herokuapp.com`. It looks like you have that backwards, your apex is pointing to `app-name.herokuapp.com` while your `www` points to `reef-inc.com` (which I assume is your apex?).

You also need to make sure your app has the correct domains added with `$ heroku domains:add expected-domain.com`

- [Custom Domains on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: fyi - the cmd line for adding domains can also be done from the settings section on your heroku dashboard.